# Can you allow a class redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, msvc12

I have a class that I am essentially trying to override from an included utility project that my project depends on.
I was hoping just creating the same class name in the main project would allow me to just simply overwrite the header that gets compiled, but instead i get

```
error C2011: 'Logger': 'class' type redefinition
```

Is there a way for me to essentially ignore the header that is compiled and overwrite it when I compile the newer version of the class?

Comment: Short Answer: No.

Comment: Once a `class`, or any entity is defined, then you can't change the definition without violating the [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: you can use another, unique, name for self class, and replace name in self code

Comment: @RbMm unfortunatly I can't access the class that calls the logger singleton, so my hope was to somehow overwrite it and create a new one with modified logic

Comment: I wonder if there is anything i can do with build events to somehow build my class first.. since the class is protected by ifdefs

Comment: what you try todo senseless

Comment: Its a problem I have to try to work around. I don't want to do it lol

Comment: if usage of that original class is already in compiled library then no, you cannot.

Comment: Is this the only way to solve your problem? It would help if you posted some code with the interface for the logger and where it gets instantiated.

Does the logger library have any configuration settings you can adjust to do what you want?

Can you inject the logic you need to via template arguments or inheritance?

Do you have access to the source code for the utility library to build a modified version?

Are you allowed to switch to a different utility library?

Comment: I am afraid that there is no way to meet you needs. Maybe you could encapsulate your rewritten class into a lib.